# creating a simple link that invokes a jsf method

Tags: jsf

i'm making a logout link and this is the code of the logout bean.

```
public void doLogout() {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user_info", null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("../index.xhtml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

in my xhtml page i have

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><h:outputLink value="#{logout.doLogout()}">Logout</h:outputLink></li>
    </ul>
```

my problem is when i get into the page, the page automatically logs me out, its invoking the logout.doLogout() method without me clicking the link itself.

i tried erasing the code inside the doLogout() and just change it to simply a Sysout, and it does invoke the method with out me clicking the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh stupid of me.. `<h:commandLink action="logout.doLogout()">Logout</h:commandLink>` does the job.

Comment: Don't forget that the `<h:commandLink>` must be inside a `<h:form>` in order to work.